# how can i go on with script if previous line command will run a server

Tags: linux, django, bash

```
cd ~/workspace/Djangocode/Djangomysite/mysite
python manage.py runserver
echo $PATH
firefox http://127.0.0.1:8000/
gnome-terminal
cd workspace/Djangocode/Djangomysite/mysite/mysite
exit 0
```

if i write a script like this. when I execute this. it will stop at 2nd line.
unless I enter ctrl+c to stop Django server.
so My question is how can I go on without stop Django server.

I'm not good at English, so if I don‘t express acurrately, please tell me.^_^

Comment: Add a '&' to the end of the command

Comment: Thank you, It really work^_^

Comment: although this method really work, and according to information online. I knew, this & means run this commend in subterminal. but when I run this script second time.an error will show :That port is already run.so does you knew another way to go on without this error?

Comment: You won't be able to start the program again until you close it because it opens a port which then can not be used again (even by the same program)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This script will do what you expect:

```
cd ~/workspace/Djangocode/Djangomysite/mysite
python manage.py runserver &
firefox http://127.0.0.1:8000/ &
gnome-terminal --working-directory=workspace/Djangocode/Djangomysite/mysite/mysite &
trap "kill -TERM -$$" SIGINT
wait
```

The last two line waiting for all process to finish or you press `ctrl-c`. Then it kills all sub processes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `screen` command.  It will be very useful if you [start getting comfortable](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) with it.